# Bloquear ENTER de diferentes Span

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

***Quisiera que los span editables no me aceptar el enter***

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let span = document.getElementById("ClienteId");
  span.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("He pulsado Enter pero no lo he escrito");
      //Aquí sigues haciendo lo que necesites
    }
  });
};

window.onload = function() {
  let span = document.getElementById("LocalId");
  span.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("He pulsado Enter pero no lo he escrito");
      //Aquí sigues haciendo lo que necesites
    }
  });
};
```

```css
.input-group-addon {
  width: 25%
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  <label class="col-sm-2"><div class="row">Cliente :</div></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="ClienteId" contenteditable="true" style="background: rgb(255,255,255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;" tabindex="10"></span>
      <input placeholder="Cliente" class="form-control input-sm" id="ClienteNombre" readonly="" type="text" tabindex="11">
    </div>
  </div>
  <label class="col-sm-2"><div class="row">Local :</div></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="LocalId" contenteditable="true" style="background: rgb(255,255,255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;" tabindex="10"></span>
      <input placeholder="Local" class="form-control input-sm" id="LocalNombre" readonly="" type="text" tabindex="11">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: podrias ser mas especifico porque ya con el preventDefault previenes el submit en un form... es decir que deseas lograr

Comment: Por que usas dos funciones `onload`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function () {
    let span1 = document.getElementById("ClienteId");
    span1.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("He pulsado Enter pero no lo he escrito");
      //Aquí sigues haciendo lo que necesites
    }
  });
  
  let span2 = document.getElementById("LocalId");
  span2.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("He pulsado Enter pero no lo he escrito");
      //Aquí sigues haciendo lo que necesites
    }
  });
};
```

```css
.input-group-addon {
  width: 25%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  <label class="col-sm-2"><div class="row">Cliente :</div></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="ClienteId" contenteditable="true" style="background: rgb(255,255,255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;" tabindex="10"></span>
      <input placeholder="Cliente" class="form-control input-sm" id="ClienteNombre" readonly="" type="text" tabindex="11">
    </div>
  </div>
  <label class="col-sm-2"><div class="row">Local :</div></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="LocalId" contenteditable="true" style="background: rgb(255,255,255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;" tabindex="10"></span>
      <input placeholder="Local" class="form-control input-sm" id="LocalNombre" readonly="" type="text" tabindex="11">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

El código que expones funciona correctamente. El problema que tenías es que las funciones `window.onload` no te estaban funcionando correctamente debido que que al tener dos la segunda sobreescribía a la primera, Al sacar el código de esas funciones e insertarlo dentro de una solamente y cambiando las `id` de las variables que recogen los `<span>` para que no sean la misma, me ha funcionado perfectamente.